# Why assertion error in Point addition?

Tags: python, secp256k1

I am doing my research on SECP256k1 but now i am facing assertion error sometimes.
I can't seem to find where it comes from, so i once thought its because the resulting point is point at affinity.

So i used order of the curve n but instead i got (None,None) not assertion error.

Please help.

Here is the error:

```
    point2 = Point(curve, Q[0], Q[1])
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ecdsa/ellipticcurve.py", line 1090, in __init__
    assert self.__curve.contains_point(x, y)
AssertionError
```

Responsible code:

```
import ecdsa
from ecdsa import SECP256k1
from ecdsa.ellipticcurve import Point
from sympy import mod_inverse
import bitcoin
import multiprocessing

curve = SECP256k1.curve
G = ecdsa.SECP256k1.generator
n= G.order()

def addp(P,Q):
    point1 = Point(curve, P[0], P[1])
    point2 = Point(curve, Q[0], Q[1])
    result_point = point1 + point2
    return result_point.x()

def find(public_key,a,b,r):
    print(hex(public_key[0]))
    if not(a == b):
        p1 = bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G,a)# (a = z/s)
        p2 = bitcoin.fast_multiply(public_key,b)# (b = r/s)
        R = addp( p1, p2) 
        tg = R % n
        if(tg == r):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Hi Alexio, your code doesn't include any import statements and only defines functions but doesn't actually execute anything. Can you share the complete code that reproduces your error?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad i have corrected the code

Comment: What functions do you invoke (`find`?), and with which arguments?

Comment: @PieterWuille it's random numbers 1 to 50 in a and b then the r value from signature along with public key

Comment: The. Code attempts to find a multiplier and a reminder (U1 and U2) in ecdsa signature such that k = U2*d+U1

Comment: @Alexiopuk2sefu Can you paste the actual code you're using?